# How to update my item in listview in the same activity where i add item into listview

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

I have 2 buttons, add and edit. The add button works and item is added to listview and store in sqlite database. But my edit button do not work, when i press edit, there is no update to my item in the listview. I search googled but all of the code uses 2 activity or dialogue, which is not what i want. I want to add and edit in one same main activity.

**This is my sqlite database**

```
public class GetFitHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "restaurantlist.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1;

    public GetFitHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // Will be called once when the database is not created
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE food_table ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 
            AUTOINCREMENT, addFood TEXT, addCalories TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int 
newVersion) {
    // Will not be called until SCHEMA_VERSION increases
    // Here we can upgrade the database e.g. add more tables
    }

    /* Read all records from food_table */
    public Cursor getAll() {
        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                "SELECT _id, addFood, addCalories FROM food_table ORDER 
BY addFood", null));
    }

/* Read a particular record from food_table with id provided */
    public Cursor getById(String id) {
        String[] args = {id};
        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                "SELECT _id, addFood, addCalories FROM food_table WHERE 
_ID = ?", args));
    }

    /* Write a record into food_table */
    public void insert(String addFood, String addCalories) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("addFood", addFood);
        cv.put("addCalories", addCalories);


        getWritableDatabase().insert("food_table", "addFood", cv);
    }

    /* Update a particular record in food_table with id provided */
    public void update(String id,String addFood, String addCalories) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        String[] args = {id};
        cv.put("addFood", addFood);
        cv.put("addCalories", addCalories);

        getWritableDatabase().update("food_table", cv, " _ID = ?", args);
    }

    /* Read a record id value from food_table */
    public String getID(Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(0));
    }
    public String getAddFood(Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(1));
    }

    public String getAddCalories(Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(2));
    }
}
```

**This is my edit button code**

```
  private View.OnClickListener onEdit = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String foodStr = addFood.getText().toString();
            String caloriesStr = addCalories.getText().toString();           
            helper.update(foodID,foodStr,caloriesStr);
        }
    };
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding the line `Log.d("ONCLCKUPDT","You clicked FoodID = " + String.valueOf(foodID) + "FoodStr = " + foodStr + " caloriesStr  = " + caloriesStr);` before the line `helper.update(foodID,foodStr,caloriesStr);`. I would guess that **foodId** is not the appropriate value. It's impossible to know where that value comes from but it is unlikely that it is the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example based upon assumptions about your other code.

The layout for the ListView (**mylistview_item.xml** in the example):-

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/editfood"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/editcalories"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="UPDATE"
    android:onClick="onclick"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cheat"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

- Note the TextView for the **id** (hidden) called cheat *(not really a cheat but it's a work around using a CursorAdapter)*.
- Note the onCLick="onclick" for the Button.
- Otherwise it is assumed that this is similar to what you have.

**GetFitHelper.java** is unchanged.

The layout for the activity **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editfood"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="New Food Name"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editcalories"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The invoking activity, in this case **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GetFitHelper helper;
    EditText addFood,addCalories;
    ListView mylistview;
    Cursor mCsr;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addFood = this.findViewById(R.id.editfood);
        addCalories = this.findViewById(R.id.editcalories);
        mylistview = this.findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
        helper = new GetFitHelper(this);

        addSomeDataIfNone();
        manageListView();

    }

    private void addSomeDataIfNone() {
        if(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(helper.getWritableDatabase(),"food_table") > 0) return;
        helper.insert("Food1","100");
        helper.insert("Food2","150");
        helper.insert("Food2","300");
    }

    private void manageListView() {
        mCsr = helper.getAll();
        if (mSCA == null) {
            mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    R.layout.mylistview_item,mCsr,
                    new String[]{"addFood","addCalories","_id"},
                    new int[]{R.id.editfood,R.id.editcalories,R.id.cheat},
                    0
            );
            mylistview.setAdapter(mSCA);
        } else {
            mSCA.swapCursor(mCsr);
        }
    }

    public void onclick(View v) {
        String foodStr = addFood.getText().toString();
        String caloriesStr = addCalories.getText().toString();
        TextView editbtn = ((View) v.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.cheat); 
        String foodID = editbtn.getText().toString();
        Log.d("ONCLCKUPDT","You clicked FoodID = " + String.valueOf(foodID) + "FoodStr = " + foodStr + " caloriesStr = " + caloriesStr);
        helper.update(foodID,foodStr,caloriesStr);
    }
}
```

The crux of the fix is the **cheat** TextView which has the **_id** column's value for the respective row. This being extracted from the TextView by getting the TextView from the parent View (The LinearLayout) using **findViewById**.

## Result

When the App is first run then it is :-

[image]

After Entering **MyNewFood2** and **1500** and then clicking button for **Food2**  then :-

[image]

The log includes the line :-

```
D/ONCLCKUPDT: You clicked FoodID = 2FoodStr = MyNewFood2 caloriesStr = 1500
```